# With Python's param package, what is class_ for a dictionary of lists of strings?

Tags: python

I'm working on some code that uses Python's param package to initialize variables:

```python
import param

class UnivariateConfig(param.Parameterized):
    input_directory = param.String(default='')
    output_directory = param.String(default='outputs')
    univariate_config = param.String(default='')
    time_types = param.List(default=[], class_=str)
    questionnaire_types = param.List(default=[], class_=str)
    label_types = param.List(default=[], class_=str)
```

I'm struggling with the [param documentation](https://param.holoviz.org/Reference_Manual/param.html), I cannot find what the values of `class_` should be for a dictionary I would normally type as

```python
model_types: Dict[str, List[str]] = {}
```

How would I rewrite that line to use `param.Dict`, i.e. what should I write in place of `WTF` in this:

```python
model_types = param.Dict(default={}, class_=WTF)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I believe that `ClassSelector` (which `Dict` inherits from) doesn't check the types of the values it contains, only the object itself (though it's possible for lists), which means you can only type `model_types: Dict` but nothing more.

The `class_` parameter is passed to `ClassSelector` as `dict` to do the type checking, and can't be overwritten (you'll get at `TypeError` if you try).